# Setting up links in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to set up a d3 force visualization with nodes and links. I have my nodes displaying properly but am having some trouble with links. Could someone take a look at my json file and then my code and guide me through the process of getting the links to display?

Here's the json data (sources and targets for links are at the bottom):

https://api.myjson.com/bins/4t8na

And here's the code for the visualization:

```js
    <script type= "text/javascript">

        var w = 1000,
            h = 650;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("width", 0)
            .style("border", "1px solid black");

        var data; // a global

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([w, h])
            .linkDistance([150])
            .charge([-1050])
            .gravity(0.5)
            .on("tick", tick);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
        
        var circles = svg.selectAll(".node");

        d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rnhq", function(error, json) {
            if (error) return console.warn(error);
            data = json;
            var nodes = data;
            console.log(data);

        force.nodes(data)//.links()
          .start();

// Update nodes.
  
    circles = circles.data(data);

    circles.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = circles.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .style("opacity", 0.75)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .on("click", click)    
      .call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r",  function(d) { return d.sector == "Academia" ? 1:5 });
            
    nodeEnter.attr("cursor", "pointer");
            
 //Update links
    var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(data.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px");
            
    links.exit().remove();        
            
    function mouseover() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(250)
            .attr('r', 10);
    }
            
    function mouseout() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(250)
            .attr('r', 5);
    }

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", ".75em")
      .attr("dy", "-0.85em").text(function (d) { return d.name });                   
    
     var tooltip = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 1000)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 900)
            .attr("height", 700)
            .attr("opacity", 0.85);            

            
    function click() {
        d3.select(tooltip).transition()
            .duration(450)
            .attr("x", 650)
    };             

    });

function tick() {
    links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
         .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    circles.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
};
        
        // create svg nodes for each json object: "sector"
                
        // create svg nodes for each json object: "name"     
        
        // load links.json
        
        // create svg links from links json file
        
        // style links
        
        // sort json objects by projects
        
        // get google map: coastal virginia
        
        // sort json objects: "name" by geography
        
        // get googe map U.S.
        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is inside your JSON links 
You have values like this:

```
{"source":52,"target":28},{"source":52,"target":29},{"source":52,"target":30},{"source":52,"target":31}
```

But there is no Node with index 52 thus everything was breaking on load.
However you code has lot of other errors like

```
circles.exit().remove();//this is incorrect coz circles in your case is not a selection
```

And many more :)

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8P7XvJmm7DxBiHHMHcqh?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `data.links` does not exist, what you have is `data[#].links`. So when you do `.data(data.links)` on your `var links = ...`, you are passing an `undefined` attribute there.

Try this:

```
var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(data)
            // ...
```

Comment: I just tried that and now I'm getting two javascript errors. One says that links.exit is not a function and the other error is referencing the tick function and is saying that links is not a function